# Relation between bias and R-square

Tags: regression, machine-learning, variance, bias, r-squared

I am trying to understand relation between bias and R-squared value in linear regression.

High bias means that the model is underfit. By this I am assuming that the R-square d will be less.
So my doubt is, can we say that bias and R-squared are inversely proportional?

Also is there any such relation between variance and R-Squared value?

Comment: Do you understand how these relate to MSE or SSE?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "bias" and what method of linear regression you are using. The reason we need this is that according to a standard statistical meaning (that the expectation of an estimate equals its estimand), standard theorems about ordinary least squares regression state that all parameter estimates are unbiased, whence there is no relationship at all between that sense of "bias" and $R^2.$

Comment: By "bias" I mean the difference between average prediction and the actual value, which is used to evaluate a linear regression model.

multiple linear regression can be taken for example.

Got your point. I was just going through bias and R-square to understand what they are and I thought if there is any relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define $R^2$, and there are several legitimate definitions, with the two below being the most reasonable to me.

$$
R^2 =\left(\text{corr}\left(\hat y, y\right)\right)^2\\
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$

$R^2 =\left(\text{corr}\left(\hat y, y\right)\right)^2$ will not care about bias. If you predict one unit too high every time, the correlation is perfect. Quoting [an answer of mine from Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114457/73930), for any real $a$ and positive $b$, $
\left(\text{corr}\left(\hat y, y\right)\right)
=
\left(\text{corr}\left(a + b\hat y, y\right)\right)
$. In fact, for nonzero $b$, $
\left(\text{corr}\left(\hat y, y\right)\right)^2
=
\left(\text{corr}\left(a + b\hat y, y\right)\right)^2
$.

Concretely, if your true values are $y=(1,2,4,6,5)$, $\hat y=(12, 13, 15, 17, 16)$ makes for terrible predictions but does have a perfect correlation with $y$. (In this example, $a=11$ and $b=1$.)

For the second formula, the numerator is just a function of the mean squared error. Since the denominator is a function of the data and not of any particular model, regard the denominator as a constant (which is is for any given data set). Then the second formula is just a decreasing function of the mean squared error. Since, all else equal, mean squared error increases when bias magnitude increases ($MSE = \text{bias}^2 + \text{var}$), you can regard that equation for $R^2$ as moving in the opposite direction of bias magnitude, yes. As bias magnitude decreases, $R^2$ increases, and as bias magnitude increases, $R^2$ decreases (assuming equal variance in both cases). This makes sense to me. Holding the variance equal, higher bias magnitude means a worse fit, which should correspond to a lower $R^2$.

Comment: To get a handle on the whole story, I would encourage you to explicitly take a derivative of $R^2$ with respect to $\text{bias}$.